# Is it safe to return memoryview from a function?

Tags: python-3.x, memoryview

I am writing program that uses TCP IP to send/receive data.
To speed up parsing and analyzing data I am currently using everywhere memoryview of the original packet and looks like it's working.
But is it safe? 
Can bytes pointed by memoryview change or be deleted by garbage collector?

I was trying to find answer in Google, Duckduckgo, Python docs, Stack**overflow** but none of them had any.

Sample code:

```
from socket import socket

def _receive(conn: socket) -> (int, bytes):
    """
    Read whole packet from connection.

    :returns length of packet, read bytes
    :rtype int, bytes
    """
    packet_length = self.__read_packet_length()

    fragments = []
    read_bytes = 0
    while read_bytes < packet_length:
        packet = conn.recv(packet_length - read_bytes)
        if not packet:
            return None
        fragments.append(packet)
        read_bytes += len(packet)

    return packet_length, b''.join(fragments)

def recv(conn: socket) -> memoryview:
    packet_len, data = _receive
    # do_stuff
    return memoryview(data)
```

While writing this post I came up with an idea to pass *buffer* into function and write data to it but I think this is still a good question.

Comment: Why do you say that you are using a memoryview?

Comment: Because it didn't crash and I don't know is it a coincidence. But thanks, edited.

Comment: You're returning an int and a byte string. They both are immutable will act like every other object in Python.

Comment: Edited. My bad, I changed the code in a last second and forgot to make some changes. Thanks.

Comment: memoryview is only a pointer (object?) to memory (if i am correct) and i found issue titled: "memoryview to freed memory can cause segfault"
https://bugs.python.org/issue15994

Comment: @Nielotz: That bug relates to a specific bug in non-owning `memoryview`s; just about any `memoryview` you're capable of constructing at the Python level (not in an extension) would be an owning view. And as is, unless you've omitted something, you're returning a view of a `bytes` object, which is largely pointless (`bytes` are already immutable, so all you're doing is hiding implementation details, not protecting against anything or adding functionality the caller couldn't access on their own), and definitely safe.

Comment: Okey, thank you very much :D
So i have quick question:
If in some function where I need read-only access to unknown length bytes, should I pass them like: 'foo(memoryview(bytes))' or just 'foo(bytes)' is enough?

Comment: I tested that, and memoryview gives significant performance boost (for huge data(2\*\*25 of bytes)). For smaller data (2\*\*5 of bytes) memoryview is slower.

https://github.com/Nielotz/python_benchmarks/blob/master/passing_bytes_to_function.py